# sql query not executed correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

My PHP/SQL code doesn't seem to work since the moment that I changed my operating system from Windows 7 to Linux Mint.

```
$AddUserToDatabase = $DatabaseConnection->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO gebruikers (' .
    '    gebruiker_naam, profiel_foto, wachtwoord,' .
    '    salt, email, timestamp, admin' .
    ') VALUES (' .
    '    :username, :profiel_foto, :wachtwoord,' .
    '    :salt, :email, :timestamp, :admin' .
    ')'
);

$AddUserToDatabase->execute(
    array(
        'username'     => $Username,
        'profiel_foto' => 'UnknownUser.png',
        'wachtwoord'   => $EncryptedPassword,
        'salt'         => $Salt,
        'email'        => $Email,
        'timestamp'    => $CurrentTimestamp,
        'admin'        => '0'
    )
);
```

I didn't change anything about the code since i changed the operating system, and I don't get any errors or warnings from the statement.

After the page has loaded i checked for the new record in de database but it isn't there :(

I find it really odd that after changing from windows to linux the code stoped working.

Does anyone know whats going on?

**EDIT:**
I just tried to execute some of the other statements but none of them seems to work. I think i have some bad configuration somewhere..

**EDIT2**

In index.php i am including the next files

```
include 'Class/Session.php';
include 'Class/Login_Register.php'

$Session->ConnectWithDatabase();
```

And this is the error, but i dont understand why it says no database selected...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected'
in /var/www/html/ScriptDeals/Classes/login_register.php:227
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/ScriptDeals/Classes/login_register.php(227):
    PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/ScriptDeals/Classes/login_register.php(81):
    LoginRegister->RegisterUser('test@live.nl', 'test', '12345678')
#2 /var/www/html/ScriptDeals/index.php(20):
    LoginRegister->FormErrorHandling()
#3 {main}
thrown in /var/www/html/ScriptDeals/Classes/login_register.php on line 227
```

This is what sets my database connection

```
function ConnectWithDatabase()
{
    global $DatabaseConnection;     

    $DatabaseUsername = 'root';     
    $DatabasePassword = 'database';         
    $DatabasePath = 'mysql:host=localhost;port:3306;dbname=scriptdeals';    

    $DatabaseConnection = new PDO(
        $DatabasePath, $DatabaseUsername, $DatabasePassword
    ); 
}
```

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Where exactly can i find it?

Comment: Add `$DatabaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Depends on the server @Szenis, usually /var/log/error.log (on Linux). You can do what Fred -ii- suggests if you do not know where the logs are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys for this question!

I found out that i had to remove port:3306 
After i did this i got a error about a missing field in the database.

I added the new field and it works now ^^

Thanks for the help, but sorry for the misplaced question!

Comment: Lordie, and here I was earlier, thinking about the same thing. *"Fred, always always go with your instinct!"* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- ^.^ Thanks for your help btw!